# How can I take the determinant on both sides in such a matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A^T BA = O,$ where $A$ is $3\times1$ matrix, then the value of $|B|$ is equal to :

(A) $1$

(B) $–1$

(C) $3$

(D) $0$

I know that the determinant of a non-square matrix is not defined, so here the matrix $B$ has to be a square matrix to be conformable for matrix multiplication. How do I conclude about its determinant in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This is not sufficient information to conclude the determinant of $B$, as we may have $A=0$.

Comment: What if for once we assume A to be non-null, how could we go about it?

Comment: Try multiplying both sides of the equation by $A$ and $A^T$ judiciously chosen

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get your point, how would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b\end{bmatrix}$ with $b=0$ and with $b\ne 0$. What nonzero vector can you choose for $A$ in either case?

P.S. This is a terrible question.